# could not find function "dbconnect" in R

Tags: r, odbc

I am running RStudio Version 1.4.1106 and R 4.0.4. Additionally, have deleted the following packages and reinstalled them; odbc, DBI, and data.table. Next, I load them (library(odbc) and library(DBI)) and so on. However, when I run the following command, I still get the following error. What else do I need to do

```
   Error in dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "DB") : 
   could not find function "dbConnect"
```

sessioninfo() gives the following result

```
 R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
 Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
 Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

 Matrix products: default

 locale:
 [1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
 [2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
 [3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
 [4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
 [5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

 other attached packages:
 [1] DBI_1.1.1  odbc_1.3.0

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       rstudioapi_0.11  magrittr_1.5     hms_0.5.3       
 [5] bit_4.0.4        tidyselect_1.1.0 munsell_0.5.0    colorspace_1.4-1
 [9] R6_2.4.1         rlang_0.4.8      fansi_0.4.1      blob_1.2.1      
[13] dplyr_1.0.2      tools_4.0.4      grid_4.0.4       gtable_0.3.0    
[17] xfun_0.19        tinytex_0.27     cli_2.1.0        ellipsis_0.3.1  
[21] bit64_4.0.5      assertthat_0.2.1 tibble_3.0.4     lifecycle_0.2.0 
[25] crayon_1.3.4     purrr_0.3.4      ggplot2_3.3.2    vctrs_0.3.4     
[29] glue_1.4.2       compiler_4.0.4   pillar_1.4.6     generics_0.0.2  
[33] scales_1.1.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
 >
```

Comment: Do you get any errors, warnings, or messages with `library(DBI);library(odbc)`? After that, do they appear in `search()` (`"package:DBI"`) or `sessionInfo()`? Please post the output from `sessionInfo()` in your question. Thanks!

Comment: @r2evans, edited the question to show sessioninfo results. No errors when I library (odbc) or library (DBI). As for search (), it says can't find function search.

Comment: That's an odd one. Sorry, no initial thoughts ...

Comment: @r2evans, not sure why it worked on the third time but resolved. 3 times I removed the packages, reinstalled, and loaded. Sorry about the waste of time.

Comment: Gremlins took a nap ... good for you, now if you can keep it that way ...